# How to return different values for each radio buttons in group box?

Tags: c#

I am a very beginner, who's trying this and that out at the moment.
I was using window form, and finally worked out how to return different value to each radio buttons, but I always have to check radBtnFromUSD first before changing to different values. Think it's due to the radBtnFromUSD_CheckedChanged part that is causing the problem, but I don't know what else to do here. I seek for your wise advise. Thank you.
Here's the code I wrote:

```
private void radBtnFromUSD_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnConfirm.Enabled = true;
        if (radBtnFromAED.Checked)
        {
            fromCurrency = Convert.ToDecimal(AED);
            return;
        }
        if (radBtnFromAUD.Checked)
        {
            fromCurrency = Convert.ToDecimal(AUD);
            return;
        }
        if (radBtnFromCAD.Checked)
        {
            fromCurrency = Convert.ToDecimal(CAD);
            return;
        }
        if (radBtnFromEUR.Checked)
        {
            fromCurrency = Convert.ToDecimal(EUR);
            return;
        }
        if (radBtnFromINR.Checked)
        {
            fromCurrency = Convert.ToDecimal(INR);
            return;
        }
        else if (radBtnFromNZD.Checked)
        {
            fromCurrency = Convert.ToDecimal(NZD);
            return;
        }
        if (radBtnFromRMB.Checked)
        {
            fromCurrency = Convert.ToDecimal(RMB);
            return;
        }
        if (radBtnFromUSD.Checked)
        {
            fromCurrency = Convert.ToDecimal(USD);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are are each of the `AED` variables?

Comment: Sorry, what are each of them?

Answer (score 0):

If You Want to Change fromCurrency Value when click radio buttons, you need to define all radiobuttons checkedchange eventhandler to same method.

likes,

```
public form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.radBtnFromAED.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.radBtnFromUSD_CheckedChanged);
    this.radBtnFromAUD.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.radBtnFromUSD_CheckedChanged);
    this.radBtnFromCAD.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.radBtnFromUSD_CheckedChanged);
    this.radBtnFromEUR.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.radBtnFromUSD_CheckedChanged);
    this.radBtnFromINR.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.radBtnFromUSD_CheckedChanged);
    this.radBtnFromNZD.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.radBtnFromUSD_CheckedChanged);
    this.radBtnFromRMB.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.radBtnFromUSD_CheckedChanged);
    this.radBtnFromUSD.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.radBtnFromUSD_CheckedChanged);

}
```

Sorry, I don't know what you want exactly.